# Programmatically embed view instance into navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, embed

I created a `tab bar` controller in which I used in the code:

```
let TV0000 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0003") as! V0003

self.setViewControllers([TV0000], animated: true)

let T0000 = UITabBarItem(title: D0000, image: nil, tag: 0)

TV0000.tabBarItem = T0000
```

But now i would like to have `TV000` embedet into a `navigation controller` how I tryed to do it is by : (N is my custum nav controller class)

```
let N = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("N") as! N

N.pushViewController(viewController: TV0000, animated: true)

self.setViewControllers([N], animated: true)

let T0000 = UITabBarItem(title: D0000, image: nil, tag: 0)

N.tabBarItem = T0000
```

All of this works fine the problem that I'm having is that the push of the `navigation controller` only seems to be non permanent and does not act like being embedded because when I go to another **tab** and come back the navigation bar is gone or it crash.

How could I make a Programmatic version of embeding the `view controller` instance into a new `navigation controller` instance ?